# Detect barcode rotation via AVCaptureMetadataOutput or Vision

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, barcode, ios-vision

I have these two barcodes:

[image]

[image]

That contains the same number: **01069327**.
The only difference is that the second one, is flipped horizontally.

I need to recognize the flip because for my scope, the products are differents.

---

I've tried using both `Vision` or `AVFoundation` without results.
`Vision` and `AVFoundation` seems not have this information or something that help me to retrieve.

### Using AVFoundation:

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
        guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
        guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
        
        let topLeft = readableObject.corners[0]
        let topRight = readableObject.corners[1]
        let bottomRight = readableObject.corners[2]
        let bottomLeft = readableObject.corners[3]

        let diffXRight = topRight.x - bottomRight.x
        let diffXLeft = topLeft.x - bottomLeft.x
        let flipThresholdX: CGFloat = 0.01
        let isFlippedHorizontally = abs(diffXRight) > flipThresholdX || abs(diffXLeft) > flipThresholdX

        print("BARCODE: \(stringValue), flipped: \(isFlippedHorizontally ? 0 : 1)\n\n")
        self.parent.didFindCode(stringValue, isFlippedHorizontally ? 0 : 1)
    }

}
```

### Using Vision (and another formula):

```
private func createRequest() -> VNDetectBarcodesRequest {
    let request = VNDetectBarcodesRequest { request, error in
        [...]
        if let stringValue = observation.payloadStringValue {
            let topLeft = observation.topLeft
            let topRight = observation.topRight
            let bottomLeft = observation.bottomLeft
            
            let angle = atan2(topRight.y - topLeft.y, topRight.x - topLeft.x) * 180.0 / .pi
            let rotationThreshold: Float = 180.0
            let isFlippedHorizontally = angle > rotationThreshold || angle < -rotationThreshold
            
            print("BARCODE: \(stringValue), flipped: \(isFlippedHorizontally ? 0 : 1)")
            self.parent.didFindCode(stringValue, isFlippedHorizontally ? 0 : 1)
        }
    }
    return request
}
```

Nothing relevant. Always get "1".

---

Seems to be a valid and retrievable information. That site, https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com as you can see from the screenshots, detect the correct "Rotation":

[image]
[image]

---

There is a way to retrieve or to extract this information?
Also using external (but free) libraries is ok.